# Is it possible to build a form action with echo $_GET?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to put url parameters in an action of a form?

for example if i have a site called:

www.example.com/form.php

and if someone goes to this site by adding this parameter:

www.example.com/form.php?hook_url=www.bla.com/index.php?id=213123

then i want to get this hook_url parameter as action on my form.

I now use:

```
<form id="ds" action="<?php echo $_GET['hook_url']; ?>" method="post" target="">
```

but it doesn't work, any idea how i can get this done

Comment: see question, this ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

> if this page name is index.php than your browser url is
>   index.php?hook_url=www.bla.com/index.php?id=213123

```
<form id="ds" action="<?php echo $_GET['hook_url']; ?>" method="post" target="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: it works, i tried it before it didnt work(maybe i overlooked something) but now it does lol thanks :) i will accept ur answer in few minutes